# Error in changing data into Date in [R]

Tags: r, as.date

I have a problem in converting a vector into date one by using `as.Date`.
Data is as below.

```
> new3<-read.csv("Total Load - Day Ahead _ Actual.csv",stringsAsFactors=F)
> colnames(new3)<- c("Date","Hour","Dayahead","Actual")
> str(new3)
'data.frame':   35044 obs. of  4 variables:
 $ Date    : chr  "01-01-2015" "01-01-2015" "01-01-2015" "01-01-2015" ...
 $ Hour    : chr  "0:00" "0:15" "0:30" "0:45" ...
 $ Dayahead: chr  "42955" "42412" "41901" "41355" ...
 $ Actual  : int  42425 42021 42068 41874 41230 40810 40461 40160 39958 
 ...
```

Here, I tried `as.Data`

```
new3$Date<-as.Date(new3$Date,"%d/%m/%Y")
```

The order of d,m,Y is right. But when I do this, it shows me NA in date info as below

```
> str(new3)
'data.frame':   35044 obs. of  4 variables:
 $ Date    : Date, format: NA NA NA NA ...
 $ Hour    : chr  "0:00" "0:15" "0:30" "0:45" ...
 $ Dayahead: chr  "42955" "42412" "41901" "41355" ...
 $ Actual  : int  42425 42021 42068 41874 41230 40810 40461 40160 39958 
 ...
```

I don't know what to do to fix it.

Can anyone help me out here? Thank you

Answer (score 3):

The step doesn't seem right

```
new3$Date<-as.Date(new3$Date,"%d/%m/%Y")
```

You should try using

```
new3$Date<-as.Date(new3$Date,"%d-%m-%Y")
```

The separator for date in your date seems to be `-` and not `/`

I'll suggest looking into `lubridate` package as well. It allows you easy ways to convert date from `character` to `date` format.

Comment: @junmouse You are welcome. Good to know it worked. You can accept the answer by clicking on tick image left of answer window.